# On the bottom end(preposition)

Tags: prepositions

> Let's talk about the **rubberized part**(black) of this cane.

[image: Rubberized cane tip]

Can you say:

> The walking cane is rubberized **on the bottom end** for better grip whenever it touches the ground.

Am I correct about the ***preposition usage?***

Comment: rubberizing means adding a layer of rubber to something. However, in contemporary English, that is known as a rubber tip, and is slipped onto the wood or metal. The end or bottom of the cane is not rubberized. A rug, on the other hand, can be rubberized by adding a layer of rubber to its back side...

Comment: Ergo, you have a "rubber-tipped cane" in your picture. Or a cane with a rubber tip.

Comment: In a nutshell, let me re-phrase it: 'This is a rubber-tipped cane **on its bottom end.**'' is it correct now?

Comment: Sorry, not quite yet:  "The bottom end of the cane is rubber tipped". The top [end] has a silver grip. If you use rubber-tipped cane, I don't think you need bottom end. A tip would be understood to be the bottom end, at least for me.

Comment: **on** is the preposition there. *On its bottom end, the cane is rubber-tipped.* Or simply "The cane is rubber-tipped".  But **on** is the correct preposition.

Comment: Yes, you can use "on the bottom (end), if you don't want to simplify the entire thing. I don't usually use a dash for things like rubber tipped when they are not in the position of an adjective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the sentence is perfectly correct and sounds natural.

Some English speakers would also just say "on the bottom" because they don't feel the need to specify the "end," but it sounds better with using it.

Comment: We obviously have different idiomatic preferences. I think including both ***bottom*** and ***end*** is a bit stylistically clumsy *unless* the context specifically requires contrasting the two different ends of something. But in OP's *specific* context I wouldn't use either anyway - I'd just say the cane is rubberized ***at the tip***.

Comment: The rubber grip at the bottom of the cane is known as a *ferrule*. So the cane comes with a ferrule.

Comment: In everyday English, we say it has a rubber tip. And rubberize is used incorrectly here. Rubberized means adding a layer of rubber to something, which is not what a rubber tip is or does.

Comment: I've used **on the bottom end** (to specify it further that it is on the bottom part) coz if I say just **at the tip** then it will be either at **the top** or on **the bottom**

Answer (score 1):

Cane description:

**The bottom of the cane has a rubber tip** and **the top of the cane has a silver grip or handle**.

The cane is rubber tipped with a silver handle (or grip).

A rubber-tipped cane with silver-handled grip.

That is how I would write it and I would  not use "on the bottom end" as that just makes it longer and less to the point.

Answer (score 1):

**On** one end of the cane there is a silver handle and **on** the other end of the cane there is a rubber tip.

**on** is correctly used there and in your examples.

There are many ways to state those facts.

> The cane has a rubber piece **at** its tip.

would also be OK.